# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-application

I get these errors When I run flutter application using android studio.How can I solve this problem

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
     emulator Android Emulator
     platforms;android-31 Android SDK Platform 31
     build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
     tools Android SDK Tools
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYaQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to you not accepting the required licences to run a project in  an emulator I think so head over to your `Tools` menu at the top of Android studio->SDK Manager-> Mark the checkbox written `Android  SDK BuildsTools` under the `SDK Toold` Tab let it download and you'll be prompted to accept the licencing. Thank you

[image]